# CSS: Intersperse images in paragraph

Tags: html, css

I have a variable number of paragraphs, and I want to intersperse images between them. I can't intersperse them in the code itself. The paragraphs are given to me as a block.

I created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4VvVL/1/, but am unsure of how to do this. I can't do:

```
<img>
<p>...</p><p>...</p>
<img>
<p>...</p><p>...</p>
<img>
<p>...</p><p>...</p>
```

but must keep the paragraphs in one block:

```
<img><img><img>
<p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p>
```

Any thoughts? I can do it in code (js, or otherwise), but I'm wondering if there is a CSS solution.

Comment: so basically you need to keeps the images in one part and paragraphs on the other

Comment: If I understand your question, you wish to make the images appear within the text, without amending the order of the HTML. If so, I don' think this is possible without using javascript or jQuery.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care that they are actually `img` tags, and you don't care about old browsers, then it can be done. See http://jsfiddle.net/4VvVL/10/ and http://jsfiddle.net/4VvVL/9/.

Whether this is practical over javascript may be questionable, but that is for you to decide.

The idea is to use the `:before` pseudo element to create a place for a background image to display, and then using `:first-child` as your base to "count" from with the adjacent sibling selector. For browsers that support it, the `:nth-child` selector is even better. See http://jsfiddle.net/4VvVL/11/.

Comment: +1 for a good answer to the OPs problem, but I would recommend against this method personally due to browser compatibility limitations.

Comment: That's why I left the "practical" use of it up to him. Everyone's situation and needs are different. I just wanted to demonstrate it could be done by CSS only. Thanks for the vote.

Comment: Very cool; the solution doesn't get better than this. I will have to revert to code since I can't support this yet. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you liked (even if you can't use at this time).